# Add informative text to PropertyPaneConfiguration

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I'd like to write some lines of text to clarify the use specific properties, like a hint below the field or as a separate text block, or even as an (i) icon next to the field

Is this at all possible?

for example

Field name

[_______]

*some additional note*

or

Field name 1

[_______]

Field name 2

[_______]

About field 1 and 2: here's how to use them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PnP SPFx property pane controls in your solution.

They provide callout value for standard property pane controls like button, text, dropdown etc.

Example:

[image]

To install them, you can do that as below:

```
npm install @pnp/spfx-property-controls --save --save-exact
```

After that in your project you can use it as below:

1) add the necessary import statement:

```
import { CalloutTriggers } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/Callout';
import { PropertyFieldLabelWithCallout } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldLabelWithCallout';
```

2) Add custom property control:

```
PropertyFieldLabelWithCallout('fakeProp', {
  calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
  key: 'LabelWithCalloutFieldId',
  calloutContent: 'Use dropdowns below to select list and list\'s field to work with',
  calloutWidth: 200,
  text: 'Select List and Field'
})
```

Reference - [PnP SPFx property pane controls](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/)

These callouts are there for standard controls mentioned below:

Label with callout - [Property Pane label control with callout](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldLabelWithCallout/)

Checkbox with callout - [Property Pane checkbox control with callout](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCheckboxWithCallout/)

Choice group with callout - [Property Pane choice group control with callout](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldChoiceGroupWithCallout/)

Toggle with callout - [Property pane toggle control with callout](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldToggleWithCallout/)

Comment: Thanks for this excellent solution

Comment: What is the use of key: 'LabelWithCalloutFieldId' for?

Comment: It is used to uniquely identify the property pane control, think of it as unique Id which you can use in your webpart. If this info is helpful, you can mark it as answer. Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `PropertyPaneLabel` for that.

Something Like:

```
{
    groupName: "Custom group",
    groupFields: [
        PropertyPaneTextField('textboxField', {
            label: "Enter a custom value"
        }),
        PropertyPaneLabel('labelField', {
            text: "This is a custom text in PropertyPaneLabel"
        })
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Check below article for more information:

[SharePoint client-side web part configurable properties in Property Pane using spfx](https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-client-side-web-part-configurable-properties-in-property-pane-using-spfx/)

Comment: Hi @JJD, Have you tried this? is it working for you??

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, thanks Ganesh